# Core Data based on SQLite: Drop indexes to reduce size and recreate them later

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Is it possible to drop the indexes in Core Data`s underlying SQLite database in order to save space and have the indexes be recreated automatically later?

What additional possibilities do exist to reduce the size of the database to a minimum and compress/zip it?

Comment: Core Data doesn't use MySQL.

Comment: Core Data can use SQLite 3 as its underlying database engine, not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for that at the Core Data API level. But you should take a look at `NSSQLitePragmasOption` as an option in the options dictionary passed to `-addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.

I often add `NSSQLiteAnalyzeOption` and `NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption` to that dictionary.

If you're really trying to squeeze space, you could always manipulate the .sqlite file manually, compressing and decompressing when the Core Data stack is not active. I've never had reason to do this myself. I'm always bound by speed, not size.